# Construct Binary Tree in O(1)?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, binary-tree

My friend was asked this question in an interview:

> Generate a finite but arbitrarily large binary tree in `O(1)`.  The method `generate()` should return a binary tree whose size is unbounded but finite.

We both cogitated over it for a long time *after* the interview, but we are only able to come up with `O(n)` solutions at best.

How would we generate in `O(1)`?  Is it even possible?  Is there something more to it?

Comment: Generate a tree with what in it? Is size zero "arbitrarily large"?

Comment: That was up to my friend.  Size should be greater than 0, though.  The nodes can be empty (without values), or 0s or 1s, etc.

Comment: This is horribly underspecified, and I doubt it accurately reflects the original form of the problem.

Comment: I can only think of making some kind of self-referential tree, but that's infinite size.

Comment: @user2357112, I too think so.. But even if we make the best of assumptions, can we still do it in `O(1)`?

Comment: You seem to have the wrong friends.

Comment: @wildplasser, maybe.  But as far as they bring me interesting questions, I am good. ;)

Comment: Maybe it was a typo or misunderstanding from their side of what O(1) means?

Comment: This seems like one of those ["bus driver" riddles](https://www.funnyandjokes.com/bus-driver.html).

Comment: @ErikElmgren, considering that it was a 30 minute interview and my friend asked questions like _what is arbitrarily large_, _is size zero arbitrarily large_, etc., I doubt that.

Comment: @J.Doe OK, if we really mean both O(1) and unbounded I would create a lazy tree that's expanding on access based on a random seed that's generated in generate().

Comment: Storing the tree in an array, like in a [binary heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap) should do the trick. Generation then becomes allocating an array, which is `O(1)` (at least as long as the intricacies of memory-allocation are ignored).

Comment: @Paul: That still leaves you with the problem of picking a size. The problem statement doesn't mention size being an input, so the answers so far have been generating the size randomly, but usual models of computing with randomness don't let you sample from an unbounded distribution in guaranteed O(1) time.

Comment: @user2357112 well, that part would need to be solved like in the other problems, or unbounded could be interpreted as the maximum-size in the other problems.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is horribly underspecified, but taking a wild guess at what they wanted:

```
def generate():
    if coinflip():
        return Node()
    return Node(left=None, right=generate())
```

O(1) expected runtime, unbounded returned tree size (and unbounded possible runtime, including running forever with probability 0). We randomly decide whether to keep making the tree deeper with probability 50% each time.

Comment: This is interesting.. I think this is the best that works within the constraints.  Thank you.

Comment: Does the question want O(1) with respect to the depth of the resulting tree? If so, this won't do. I agree the question is rather vague.

Comment: This takes constant *expected* time, but is not technically O(1)... Although it would be O(1) if you did the same thing in Haskell, or implemented right() as a getter.

Comment: This may return an infinite tree.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès: Not quite. What it can do (with probability 0) is run forever without returning, assuming unlimited memory and stack size.

Comment: @user2357112 right it may not return trying to generate an infinite tree. You may then add some stopping condition to ensure finiteness (determine the bound at the beginning?)

Comment: The possibility of running forever is essentially unavoidable. By applying [Konig's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_lemma) to the tree of random decisions the algorithm can make (not the tree the algorithm returns), we see that if the algorithm chooses from a finite number of possibilities each time (so decision nodes have finite degree), and the size of the returned tree is unbounded (requiring the decision tree to be infinite), then there must be an infinite simple path in the tree, from which the existence of an infinite execution path follows.

Comment: To avoid this, we would need to be able to choose from an infinite number of possibilities in a single step.

Answer (score 3):

Generate a random number that is smaller than the size of available memory.
Then, pick any byte array of that length in local memory.

Congratulations! You've just created a random binary tree. One of the representations of a binary tree is an array.
See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Arrays

Comment: Yeah. Sounds correct but it only covers a subset of actually possible arbitrary trees.

Comment: The task didn't specify to create all possible trees - just "a finite but arbitrarily large binary tree" which I think means anyone and just one.

Answer (score 2):

This is both O(1) runtime and unbounded. The contents of the tree is determined during `generate()`.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>

class node {
  std::string _value;
  unsigned int _left_seed;
  unsigned int _right_seed;
  bool _right_exists;
  bool _left_exists;

public:
  inline node(unsigned int seed,std::string const& value)
  {
    _value = value;
    _left_seed = rand_r(&seed);
    _right_seed = rand_r(&seed);
    _left_exists = true; //rand_r(&seed)>5; // depends on what 'unbounded' means
    _right_exists = true; //rand_r(&seed)>5;
  }

  inline node *get_left()
  {
    if (!_left_exists) return NULL;

    unsigned int tseed = _left_seed;
    char ch = '0' + rand_r(&tseed) % 5;

    return new node(tseed,std::string(_value) + ch);
  }

  inline node *get_right()
  {
    if (!_right_exists) return NULL;

    unsigned int tseed = _right_seed;
    char ch = '5' + rand_r(&tseed) % 5;

    return new node(tseed,std::string(_value) + ch);
  }

  inline const std::string& get_value()
  {
    return(_value);
  }
};

static node *generate()
{
  std::string str("");
  return new node(random(),str);
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain your logic?

Comment: @J.Doe I return a generator that to an external observer is an actual tree, but the only work that is done in generate() is making the seed and instantiating the top node. If the tree is descended into, and after that the lower nodes are discarded, and finally re-descended, the tree will look the same because I use the same PRNG seed. Don't know if I can be more specific unless there is some particular part someone is wondering about.

Comment: It's questionable whether this really counts as *generating* the whole tree in O(1), or whether the expense of generating additional nodes on demand should be counted toward tree generation costs, but I'm not going to argue about whether this code fits the spec when we barely have anything of a spec anyway.

Comment: @user2357112, I know I'm half-cheating. I generate a tree without creating a tree data-structure. As the spec is written I don't see another solution to both hard O(1) and really unbounded except possibly always using infinite time to generate it, would that still be O(1)?

Comment: (This suffers from *not* being finite just like (the first two revisions of) [user2357112's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49502161/3789665) - both can be fixed by limiting the number of nodes during generation.)

Answer (score 1):

**This is a very good example of stupid interview questions.**

The solution is to generate a single node and return it. The special property of this tree is that the getLeft() and the getRight() are a facade and generate the node when the function is called instead of creating all nodes upfront.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
  Node root = new Node(); // O(1)
}

public class Node {
  private Node left, right;
  private boolean isLeftEvaluated = false, isRightEvaluated = false;

  public Node getLeft() {
    if (! isLeftEvaluated) {
      left = new Node();
    }

    isLeftEvaluated = true;
    return left;
  }

  public Node getRight() {
    if (! isRightEvaluated) {
      right = new Node();
    }

    isRightEvaluated = true;
    return right;
  }
}
```

Nobody who has good experience in programming will come close to even thinking about this solution with that kind of underspecified requirement.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.dailycodingproblem.com/blog/big-tree/

```
import random

class Node:
    def __init__(self, val, left=None, right=None):
        self.val = val
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

def generate():
    root = Node(0)

if random.random() < 0.5:
    root.left = generate()
if random.random() < 0.5:
    root.right = generate()

return root
```

Comment: The average number of nodes at every depth is 1 so the expected number of nodes is infinite so the running time is also infinite.  But, change `0.5` to anything smaller than `0.5` then you have expected running time finite and it is possible to generate any finite binary tree.

Answer (score 0):

I analyzed the requirements a bit. They do not say what kind of tree they want, (Complete, skewed etc ..) nor the underlying data structure. So if we assume that they want a complete binary tree, any array can be considered as a complete binary tree. So we could return an arbitrary sized array. To fill the array in (1) we could use something like memcopy to fill it junk value. Or if it's implemented in a c like language, use the existing junk values as data. This something that I just thought about. This may not be right at all. Again the requirements are very vague.